# AJAX Live Search showing results ONLY if it starts with the same first letter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax live search bar that I made using this w3school example. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

How do I get it to only show results that have the letters in the same order beginning with the first letter, as opposed to matching any chunk of letters in the word. For example, for the "COMPUTER" to be shown as a result you have to have typed "COM..." as opposed to "PUTER".

I believe i have narrowed it down to being somwhere in here:

```
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
  if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    //find a link matching the search text
    if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint="<a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint . "<a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your conditional syntax that search for items:

```
//find a link matching the search text
if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
```

this is making the search `$q` in any part of item, what you want to do is to search only if it begins with `$q` , so you have to change syntax:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue), strtolower($q)) === 0)
```

So now it will search if matches at the beginning (position === 0). You also notice that I use `strtolower()` in both compared values, this is because `strpos()` is case sensitive, and `stristr()` isn't.

Could you try now changing this line and tell us if it worked?